# Google analytics is showing magento orders twice with different numbers

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

Since April, orders are being sent twice to google analytics, the strange thing is that one is OK with the format 9XXXXXXXXX, and another one is not fine with format 4XXX

I have no idea what should I check to prevent this.

my website is www.theprinterdepo.com, you are free to create demo orders with visa number 41111111111111

[image]

This code I found it in Ga.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_GoogleAnalytics
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * GoogleAnalitics Page Block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_GoogleAnalytics
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_Core_Block_Text
{
    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.1.1
     * @see self::_getOrdersTrackingCode()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuoteOrdersHtml()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.1.1
     * self::_getOrdersTrackingCode()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderHtml()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.1.1
     * @see _toHtml()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccount()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific page name (may be customized via layout)
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPageName()
    {
        return $this->_getData('page_name');
    }

    /**
     * Render regular page tracking javascript code
     * The custom "page name" may be set from layout or somewhere else. It must start from slash.
     *
     * @link http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview
     * @link http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html
     * @param string $accountId
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getPageTrackingCode($accountId)
    {
        $pageName   = trim($this->getPageName());
        $optPageURL = '';
        if ($pageName && preg_match('/^\/.*/i', $pageName)) {
            $optPageURL = ", '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($pageName)}'";
        }
        return "
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)}']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'{$optPageURL}]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
";
    }

    /**
     * Render information about specified orders and their items
     *
     * @link http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addTrans
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getOrdersTrackingCode()
    {
        $orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds))
        ;
        $result = array();
        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
                $address = $order->getBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
            }
            $result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addTrans', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
                $order->getIncrementId(), Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName(), $order->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                $order->getBaseTaxAmount(), $order->getBaseShippingAmount(),
                $this->jsQuoteEscape($address->getCity()),
                $this->jsQuoteEscape($address->getRegion()),
                $this->jsQuoteEscape($address->getCountry())
            );
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addItem', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
                    $order->getIncrementId(),
                    $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku()), $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()),
                    null, // there is no "category" defined for the order item
                    $item->getBasePrice(), $item->getQtyOrdered()
                );
            }
            $result[] = "_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);";
        }
        return implode("\n", $result);
    }

    /**
     * Render GA tracking scripts
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('googleanalytics')->isGoogleAnalyticsAvailable()) {
            return '';
        }
        $accountId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ACCOUNT);
        return '
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';
        (document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName(\'body\')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
' . $this->_getPageTrackingCode($accountId) . '
' . $this->_getOrdersTrackingCode() . '

//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->';
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your google analystics javascript look like?

Comment: this is magento, its supposed to insert it automatically, where can I find it in magento?

Comment: @ChrisBain I found Ga.php and inserted the code in the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution was quite simple:
I had installed and enabled a module for tracking, but forgot to disable Magento's core tracking capacity (under Configuration>Sales>Google API).

Answer (score 3):

The GA ecommerce code is being called twice on your order confirmation page. The code in Ga.php that you listed seems to be generating the tracking with the order numbers in the 9XXXXXXXXX format.

It's hard to say where the other GA ecommerce tracking code is coming from, but if you inspect the page via developer tools in Chrome or firebug in Firefox, you should be able to see the other tracking code that's getting rendered in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24813807-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
'4598', 
'English',
'34.3270',
'0.0000', 
'19.4670',
'Some City', 
'New York', 
'United States' 
]);



_gaq.push(['_addItem','4598','Q1396A','Universal 21lb Basic Bond Paper Roll 24 inch x 150ft','','14.86', '1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); 
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();</script>
```

Maybe seeing the format in which this code is being added will help you search through your code to see if there's a module you're using that happens to be adding it?

Comment: I guess the problem in magento its in success.phtml page, I guess that I can delete the code from that file because its already injected by magento in some way.